# Google Api Translate v2 .net : How many characters can be sent via service.Translations.List()?

Tags: google-translate, google-api-dotnet-client

please answer my question regarding the implementation of the following method in Google Translate .net api v2:

How many characters can be sent as a string with this method at most?

```
var response = service.Translations.List(source, targetLanguageCode).Execute();
```

I have searched the Internet and found a general answer which is as follows:
The maximum length of a request as GET is 2000 characters, whereas it is 5000 characters as POST. However, this rule does not appear to be true about this library. Using this method for instance, I could send and translate a string as long as 19500 characters; however, I sometimes encountered the following error:

> Invalid Uri: The Uri string is too long

Thanks

--EDITED

I was wrong about POST size limitation. Based on this link and other resources, there is no limitation.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Can you please link to the right documentation in your description? The client library implements an interceptor to replace a GET query that is more than 2000 chars. I don't think that there is any limitation on a POST request, but I would be happy to hear more... The interceptor is available here: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/GoogleApis.Core/Apis/Http/MaxUrlLengthInterceptor.cs, and it's used by default: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Services/BaseClientService.cs#L169

Comment: @peleyal Thanks for introducing your git project. Unfortunately, I still get the same error on large strings. Should I change encoding or modify my request before sending?

Comment: @peleyal I send several test requests using this client API. I could send request and receive processed translation up to 25000 characters (with space and specials).

Comment: So the problem only occurs when you use more than 25000 chars?